# CefSharp GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name,

Tags: c#, selenium, opengl, gpu, cefsharp

I plugged in selenium and CefSharp to work together however I am getting weird errors being logged...

> [0217/000149:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(13988)] [.Compositor-000001C8F5CE0570]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
>   [0217/000149:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(7639)] [.Compositor-000001C8F5CE0570]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
>   [0217/001125:WARNING:dns_config_service_win.cc(673)] Failed to read DnsConfig.
>   [0217/003937:WARNING:raw_channel_win.cc(532)] WriteFile: The pipe is being closed. (0xE8)
>   [0217/003937:WARNING:proxy_message_pipe_endpoint.cc(50)] Failed to write enqueue message to channel

Code looks following (Atm app is more for debugging than for it's original purpose):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ChromiumWebBrowser _browser;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            _browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com/gmail/about/")
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            };

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            var options = new ChromeOptions { BinaryLocation = Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Split(new[] { "bin" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0], @"support\cef_binary_3.2556.1368.g535c4fb_windows64_client\Release\cefclient.exe") };
           // options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
            var cefDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            cefDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/gmail/about/"); //Somewhere here error is raised that then writes a log file and pops up alert that derails whole application
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (isAlertPresent(cefDriver)) {
              //  cefDriver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept(); //This fails to close opened error dialog
            }
        }

        public bool isAlertPresent(ChromeDriver driver)
        {
            try
            {
                driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                return true;
            }   
            catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex)
            {
                return false;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it had something to do with blocking on UI thread..

Code below works ok.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var username = textBox1.Text;
            var password = textBox2.Text;

            if (new[] { username, password }.Any(o => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(o)))
            {
                label3.Text = "One of'em boxes is empty";
                return;
            }

            await PassLogin(username, password);
        }

        async Task PassLogin(string username, string password)
        {
            await Task<ChromeDriver>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var options = new ChromeOptions { BinaryLocation = Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Split(new[] { "bin" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0], @"support\cef_binary_3.2556.1368.g535c4fb_windows64_client\Release\cefclient.exe") };
                var cefDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                return cefDriver;
            }).ContinueWith(async cefDriverTask =>
            {
                var cefDriver = await cefDriverTask;
                cefDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/gmail/about/");
                cefDriver.FindElementByCssSelector(".gmail-nav__nav-link.gmail-nav__nav-link__sign-in").Click();
                var user = cefDriver.FindElementById("Email");
                user.SendKeys(username);
                cefDriver.FindElementById("next").Click();
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                var pass = cefDriver.FindElementById("Passwd");
                user.SendKeys(password);
                cefDriver.FindElementById("signIn").Click();
            });
        }
    }
}
```